# Plot a function (constant on each square=CELL) in paraview using vtk file

Tags: paraview, vtk

I'm trying to plot the solution of a numerical method using a vtk file in paraview.

The structure is very simple, and I going to explain with an example. I have a mesh of the unit square [0,1]x[0,1] consisting on 4 squares (CELLS) of equal dimensions, and then this mesh has 9 POINTS. I have a constant solution on each one of these 4 squares.

I'm trying to use the following vtk file, but does not work, What I'm doing wrong?

````
# vtk DataFile Version 3.0
Little example
ASCII

DATASET UNSTRUCTURED_GRID
POINTS 9 DOUBLE
  0.0  0.0  0.0
  0.5  0.0  0.0
  1.0  0.0  0.0
  0.0  0.5  0.0
  0.5  0.5  0.0
  1.0  0.5  0.0
  0.0  1.0  0.0
  0.5  1.0  0.0
  1.0  1.0  0.0

CELLS 4 20
  4  0  1  3  4
  4  1  2  4  5
  4  3  4  6  7
  4  4  5  7  8

CELL_TYPES 4
  9
  9
  9
  9

CELL_DATA 4
SCALARS pressure DOUBLE
LOOKUP_TABLE DEFAULT
    0.00000
    1.00000
    2.00000
    3.00000
```
````

Comment: The connectivity of cells is not correct. The correct order is counter-clockwise. For example, for cell 1, it should be "4 0 1 4 3".

Comment: Thanks @ChennaK !! that solves my problem.